# AVAudioPlayer sounds will not play under 1 second apart

Tags: xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

I have 0.2sec long sound file "beep.caf" that I am trying to get to play rapidly. If I set the sounds to play 1 second apart, they play just fine, but if I set them to play any less like 0.8, only the first sound plays. I have the same problem using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound too.

To play the sound twice rapidly I have the following function:

```
func runAfterDelay(delay: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

I first setup my sound in the viewDidLoad with the following:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("beep", ofType: "caf")!
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do{
        self.startBeep = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        self.startBeep.prepareToPlay()

    }catch{
        print("Audio didn't load")
    }
```

Then when a button is pressed the following code is run:

```
let start_time:Double = 1.0
let end_time:Double = start_time + 0.8

    runAfterDelay(start_time ) {
        self.startBeep.play()
    }
runAfterDelay(end_time ) {
        self.startBeep.play()
    }
```

I have tried to stop the sound before the next play, but that doesn't help either. I have even duplicated the should file (beep & beepStop) to see if it had something to do with playing the same sound file and I get the same problems.

Any ideas??

Comment: Yes, What about using use garage band to create a bigger soundbite, which you play one second apart. :)

Comment: I am not sure how that would help. I will add that the time between the start beep and end end beep is defined by a user action and could be as low as 0.5 of a second.

Comment: Maybe I got this the wrong way around, are you sure beep.caf is just 0.2 seconds long. Can you put in a trigger to detect the play completion, and time the whole thing perhaps ?

Comment: Time length of the sound file 0.200430839002268.

 Even so, I have tested if the sound is playing and it usually still is, then I try self.startBeep.stop() and then self.startBeep.play() with no luck.

Comment: If you create 2 instances of `AVAudioPlayer`, then simply play the second one at the specified time interval after the first one, it should work fine. If for some reason that solution does not work either, then I would recommend using `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`. `AVPlayer` is a much more precise player overall

Comment: I think I am going to have to try using the AVPlayer. I have tried 2 instances and received the same issue. I have also tried with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound  and had the same issue. I am beginning to wonder if it has something to do with the runAfterDelay func.

Comment: thats very interesting, I wonder the same thing, let us know if this works with `AVPlayer` please!

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. My milliseconds was off. So instead of 0.5, it was trying to fire at 0.05 which was too fast. Fixing the milliseconds to tenths from hundreds fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the time and not the players. The delay time was supposed to be in a 10th of a millisecond but was a 100th of a millisecond (.1 vs .01) which was so short of time between beeps that it often didn't fire accurately. A false positive was created when the time was set to 1.0 seconds.